# Why isn't simplecov checking any of my rails views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, code-coverage, test-coverage, simplecov

I installed simplecov on a new rails project, but it's not checking the view files.  After reading some [other posts on this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075516/simple-cov-gem-missing-untested-files) I've updated my application as follows, but no dice.  How do I get simplecov to test my views too?

**spec/spec_helper.rb**

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start do
  add_filter "/spec/"
  add_filter "/config/"
  add_group "Models", "app/models"
  add_group "Controllers", "app/controllers"
  add_group "Views", "app/views"
  # TODO: why isn't SimpleCov showing my view files?
end
...
```

**config/environments/test.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Do not eager load code on boot. This avoids loading your whole application
  # just for the purpose of running a single test. If you are using a tool that
  # preloads Rails for running tests, you may have to set it to true.
  config.eager_load = true 
  ...
```

[image: simplecov not testing views]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test code coverage for Rails ERB templates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030909/how-to-test-code-coverage-for-rails-erb-templates)